# How to fix Go build error "can't load package" with Go modules?

Tags: go, go-modules, go-build

I'm setting up a new project using Go modules with [this tutorial](https://bogotobogo.com/GoLang/GoLang_Modules_1_Creating_a_new_module.php), and then trying to build it.

The module is located in a folder outside of the $GOPATH with the following structure:

```
example.com
├── my-project
├── ├── main
├── ├── ├── main.go
├── ├── go.mod
```

I've run `go mod init example.com/my-project` in directory `example.com/my-project` and created the go.mod file shown above.

`main.go` has basic contents:

```golang
package main

import (
"fmt"
)
func main(){
 fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
}
```

After attempting to run `go build` in directory `example.com/my-project`, I receive the following error message:

`can't load package: package example.com/my-project: unknown import path "example.com/my-project": cannot find module providing package example.com/my-project`.

I've also attempted to run `go build` in directory `/`, outside of `example.com/my-project`, and I get similar, failing results:

`can't load package: package .: no Go files in ...`

I'm probably getting some basic thing wrong, so thanks for your patience and any help you can give.

Comment: You can't run `go build` in `example.com/my-project`, because there's nothing to build. The main package you're building is called `example.com/my-project/main`

Comment: Oh, I see! If you make that into an answer I'll vote for it.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386846/how-can-i-improve-this-downvoted-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no need for the directory main,
just move your main.go and go.mod to example.com/my-project and it will work.

Project root should look like:

```
.
├── go.mod
└── main.go
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was that the variables GOMOD and GOWORK were taking other values different from the project I solved it by executing the command `go env` and verifying the values of those variables and deleting the files of that address.

Then I removed the `go.mod` and `go.sum` file from the project and ran the following commands again:

```
go mod init projectName
go mod tidy
go run ./...
```

And it worked perfectly.